# Unity Oculus VR import model during runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Is it possible to have a GUI to import a local (stored in an Oculus Quest 2) modelfile and then assign it to an new gameobject during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "local". If you're shipping the model with your Unity project, you could use [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) to load and instantiate a model from the `Resources` folder (and its sub-directories).

If you're adding a model outside of the Unity application, you can use the `Application.persistentDataPath` property to access a file directory in the local storage of your Quest 2 device.

Comment: The model will not be inside the compiled resources, it should be imported from the local storage of my quest 2 device